# SQL Summarise Multiple Rows in a Single Row

Tags: sql, pivot, row

I've been through and seen this question asked in a million different ways, but none of the answers seem to fit my particular needs, so I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a table like below:

```
URN | CustomerID | Selection
----------
1 | 1 | 16A
----------
2 | 1 | 16B
----------
3 | 1 | 16C
----------
4 | 2 | 16A
----------
5 | 2 | 16C
----------
6 | 1 | 16D
----------
6 | 1 | 16E
----------
```

What I'd like is an export table or query that looks like the below (limited to 5 columns for selection):

```
CustomerID | Selection 1 | Selection 2 | Selection 3 | Selection 4 | Selection 5
----------
1 | 16A | 16B | 16C | 16D | 16E
----------
2 | 16A | 16C 
----------
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the ANSI-standard `row_number()` with a pivoting method.  I prefer conditional aggregation:

```
select CustomerID,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then selection end) as selection_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then selection end) as selection_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then selection end) as selection_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then selection end) as selection_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then selection end) as selection_5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CustomerID order by urn) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to go dynamic and assuming SQL Server

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(concat('Selection ',Row_Number() over (Partition By CustomerID Order By URN) )) From YourTable For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [CustomerID],' + @SQL + '
  From  (Select CustomerID,Selection,Col=concat(''Selection '',Row_Number() over (Partition By CustomerID Order By URN) ) From YourTable) A
 Pivot (Max([Selection]) For [Col] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
CustomerID  Selection 1 Selection 2 Selection 3 Selection 4 Selection 5
1           16A         16B         16C         16D         16E
2           16A         16C         NULL        NULL        NULL
```